# Minimal polynomial for trig function

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, minimal-polynomials

I am trying to find the minimal polynomial of $\tan \theta $ over $\mathbb{Q}(\tan 2\theta$). I'm assuming that $0 <2\theta < \frac{\pi}{2}.$ If I assume that $\tan \theta \notin \mathbb{Q}(\tan 2\theta),$ then the minimal polynomial is $ x^2 + \frac {2}{\tan 2\theta}x -1=0.$ I can see that for particlar choice of $\theta$, for example, $\theta = \frac{\pi}{6},$ I have $\tan \theta \in \mathbb{Q}(\tan 2\theta).$ Could you help me find some values of $\theta$ such that $\tan \theta \notin \mathbb{Q}(\tan 2\theta)$? Thank so much. Any help/suggestions would be apprecited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

Show that $\tan(\frac{\pi}{8}) \notin \mathbb Q$.

Comment: Thanks so much. It's more than hints.

Answer (score 3):

The hint by N.S. gives the solution. Let me add more details. Let me denote $\tan\theta$  by $x$ and $\tan2\theta$ by $a$. The usual formula tells us 
$$a=\frac{2x}{1-x^2}$$
This can be rewritten as a quadratic relation between $a$ and $x$ as 
$$ax^2+2x-a=0$$ which has discriminant  $4(1+a^2)$.

As the range of tan function is whole of real numbers $a$ can take any integer value. For all integers $a$ we can see $(1+a^2)$ (being an integer next to a square) is not a square and hence the discriminant is not a square of an integer. (not can it be a square of a rational number).
So the root $x=\tan\theta$ is irrational whenever $\tan2\theta$ is a non-zero  integer.

Comment: Except, of course, for the case $a=0$

Comment: Thank you so much. It makes more sense.